# Phonegap+JQuery Mobile: How to fire a popup from the Android menu button?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I created this snippet in a simple Phonegap 3.1 app, based on the JQuery Mobile popup documentation:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-theme="e">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;" data-theme="e">
        <li><a href="javascript:loadHelp()">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:loadAbout()">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-role="button">
    Click for menu
</a>
```

Clicking the button brings up the menu.

I also have this snippet in an external .js file:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);
})

function onMenuKeyDown() {
    alert("Menu key pressed!");
    // what goes here?      
}
```

Pressing the menu button brings up the alert, so I know the listener is working. Now, I want to add some code to the onMenuKeyDown() function so it will bring up the menu loaded by the button in the first snippet. The code needs to be equivalent to clicking

```
<a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup">Click here</a>
```

How would I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found a way to do this. It works, but it seems kind of hacky. Suggestions for other ways to do this are welcome.

First, make the original link invisible and give it an ID:

```
<a href="#popupMenu" style="display: none;" id="hammerTime" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" >
     Can't touch this! 
</a>
```

Then have the menu button click the invisible link:

```
function onMenuKeyDown() {
    // alert("Menu key pressed!");
    $("#hammerTime").click()      
}
```

Hopefully someone else will find this useful along the way.